# Redirect to other component on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a way, in React, to redirect the user to, let's say, the homepage, if the user refreshes the page?

I can trigger an alert when the refresh button is pressed, but I cannot manage to actually redirect to the about-page (in this case). Any ideas?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();

    return () => {
      if (window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        alert("Redirect")
        return <Redirect to="/About"></Redirect>
      }

    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: How about setting up react-routers?

Comment: Is that possible? I render some stuff in this component, but if user refreshes the page, the page should jump to "About".

Comment: You can maintain a `state`. Let's say if the page loads and this state is empty, you'll redirect to a different component using react router.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();

    return () => {
      if (window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
         window.location.href = "/About"
      }

    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: That was easy. Thanks!